# How to use Magiczoom Callbacks

Tags: magiczoom

The [magiczoom documentation describes callbacks](https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoom/integration/#api) that will execute at given times, but it's unclear how to use or assign those callbacks.

For example, how would I print a console message `onZoomReady`?

The closest I've found is a `MagicZoom.defaults.onready` property, but it's unclear how to set it via javascript (my attempts aren't working as expected).

Comment: Can you post some of your attempts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callbacks are configured via **mzOptions**, for example:

```
var mzOptions = {
    onZoomReady: function() { … } }
;
```

Or:

```
var mzOptions = {};
mzOptions.onZoomReady = function() { … };
```

Comment: Such callbacks as described above cannot be configured to change data-options. 

Instead, a separate callback can be set via the mzOptions, for example:

`<script>
    var mzOptions = {
          onZoomReady: function(zoom_id) { }
    }
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
MagicZoom.registerCallback('onUpdate', 
    function() {
        console.log('onUpdated', arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]);
    });
```

That will log stuff in the console like this:

```
onUpdated (id-of-mz-wraper) (html of old element) (html of new element)
```

Other options that you can use are as per the documentation:

```
MagicZoom.registerCallback('onZoomReady', function() {
  console.log('onReady', arguments[0]);
  });

MagicZoom.registerCallback('onZoomIn', function() {
  console.log('onZoomIn', arguments[0]);
  });

MagicZoom.registerCallback('onZoomOut', function() {
  console.log('onZoomOut', arguments[0]);
  });
```